# Error in processing soap fault with http 500 error in DataPower

Tags: soap, fault, http-error, ibm-datapower

I am new to DataPower.

I have created Multi Protocol Gateway (MPG) and create a processing policy with 3 rules.

1) Request Rule
2) Response Rule
3) Error Rule

All rules are having '*' in the matching action.

Whenever I am getting 'http 500' error with soap fault. Process to go to Error rule. Response rule is getting executed.

Is there any thing I have to change in matching action for response rule.

I have tried to change the sequence of rules in policy.

Comment: @ Tripp Kinetics . thanks for add tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to turn off 'Process Backend Errors' under 'Advanced' tab for MPG. 
if it is on, Response rule process the errors also